# How do I align my custom Tab Capsule Indicator with my custom Tab Bar in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, widget

Good Evening everyone, I am newbie in programming and trying my hands on creating custom widgets and UI elements in Flutter.

I have created a custom Capsule Tab Indicator and a custom Tab widget, but I am facing some alignment issues between the two.
(The Capsule Indicator won't align in the centre with the text on the Tab)

This is the custom tab widget I have created:

```
class CustomTab extends StatelessWidget {
  final String text;
  final double width;

  const CustomTab({Key? key, required this.text, this.width = 50})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      constraints: BoxConstraints(minWidth: width),
      child: Tab(
        text: text,
        height: 36,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And this is the Capsule Tab Indicator:

```
class CapsuleTabIndicator extends Decoration {
  final BoxPainter _painter;

  CapsuleTabIndicator({
    Color color = Colors.black,
    double radius = 2.0,
  }) : _painter = _CapsulePainter(color, radius);

  @override
  BoxPainter createBoxPainter([VoidCallback? onChanged]) => _painter;
}

class _CapsulePainter extends BoxPainter {
  final Paint _paint;
  final double radius;

  _CapsulePainter(Color color, this.radius)
      : _paint = Paint()
          ..color = color
          ..isAntiAlias = true;

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Offset offset, ImageConfiguration cfg) {
    final double width = cfg.size!.width;
    final double height = cfg.size!.height;

    const double minWidth = 60.0;

    final Offset circleOffset =
        offset + Offset(width / 2.0, height - radius + 2.5);
    final RRect rRect = RRect.fromRectAndRadius(
        Rect.fromCenter(
            center: circleOffset,
            width: (width - radius * 4).clamp(minWidth, double.infinity),
            height: radius * 2.0),
        Radius.circular(radius));

    canvas.drawRRect(rRect, _paint);
  }
}
```

Finally, this is how I am using them both:

```
late TabController _tabController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _tabController = TabController(length: 2, vsync: this);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _tabController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: CustomScrollView(
        slivers: [
          SliverAppBar(
            title: const Text('My App'),
            pinned: true,
            floating: true,
            bottom: PreferredSize(
              preferredSize: const Size.fromHeight(44.0),
              child: TabBar(
                controller: _tabController,
                indicator: CapsuleTabIndicator(),
                indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.label,
                isScrollable: true,
                labelColor: Colors.black,
                unselectedLabelColor: Colors.black54,
                labelStyle:
                    const TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w600, fontSize: 13),
                unselectedLabelStyle:
                    const TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w600, fontSize: 13),
                tabs: const [
                  CustomTab(text: 'Tabuloid 1'),
                  CustomTab(text: 'Tabuloid 2'),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          SliverFillRemaining(
            child: TabBarView(
              controller: _tabController,
              children: const [
                Center(child: Text('Tab 1')),
                Center(child: Text('Tab 2')),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

I have tried many methods but I am stuck at this. I really need some guidance.

Any help would be really appreciated.